# What is the difference between M323R4GA3BB0-CQK & M323R4GA3BB0-CQKOD

Tags: memory

I have 2 Samsung Dimm modules with the part numbers ( M323R4GA3BB0-CQK, M323R4GA3BB0-CQKOD)

The only difference between them is the OD at the end.

What is the meaning of this OD? what does it stand for? are there any other suffix?

Comment: There is also a `M323R4GA3BB0-CQKOL` (***OL***). I'm not sure what the difference is, but it might simply be batches/variations of manufacturing and nothing in the specs. And you can see that the OD and OL suffixes aren't listed as products by Samsung separately (https://semiconductor.samsung.com/dram/module/)

Comment: And you can see that as well from the fact that https://ram.userbenchmark.com/Search?searchTerm=M323R4GA3BB0 has no simple CQK models, only CQKOD and CQKOL

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will perhaps contact the manufacturer and see if they will be willing to answer the question.